Как настроить авторизацию laravel и vue.js при этом они на расположены на разных хостах
Решил полностью разделить бэкэнд и фронтенд часть. Бэк и фронт запускаются на разных локальных хостах vue(localhost://5173) а laravel(localhost:127.0.0.1 ). Столкнулся с проблемой того что при входе в учётную запись на стороне фронта не могу осуществить вход. В config(laravel) пытался настроить cors по документации всё равно не могает и прописывал чтобы запросы шли именно с хоста vue.js всё равно выкидывает ошибку 419. Подскажите кто уже делал проеткы таким образом какие действия нужно совершать или где можно найти информацию по данному вопросу.

Так а с запросами заголовок авторизации хоть передаётся?

Зачем это бессмысленное усложнение жизни самому себе? В 99.99% сайтов это не нужно. Оставьте фронт и бек на одном домене и не изобретайте себе грабли на ровном месте.

Дело в том что всё делается на  sanctum . В документации есть такая конструкция
function login(){
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login', {email:emailInput.value, password:passwordInput.value }).then(response => {
console.log(response)
});
});
}
В первом axios запрашивается токен но как оказалось он не сохраняется на фронте и соответственно не получается зайти

CORS это сложная система с неочевидными настройками, поэтому не нужно самому себе создавать трудности без реальной необходимости. Используйте один домен и забудьте про CORS.

@AlexeyTen не согласен про 99.99% сайтов При появлении у приложения, которое использует Cookie авторизацию, второго фронтенда (не доведи Господи, веб) идея вынести бекенд на  api.* являється чуть ли не единственным способом сделать всё адекватно. А вообще да, незачем на ровном месте усложнять себе жизнь

@Oleksandr ну пусть будет 99.5%

@AlexeyTen  ну почему-же) Задание - для app.com сделать next.app.com с редизайном фронтенда, но чтобы app.com работал штатно. Бекенд такой-же. Хотят, чтобы авторизация на одном интерфейсе работала и на другом. И всё, попали)

@Oleksandr, у них общий домен. CORS не нужен. Ну и мало у кого реально есть или будут в обозримом будущем такие задачи.

@AlexeyTen и что, что домен одинаковый? Порты разные. CORS валидируються на уровне origin, а порт - это часть origin. Ну и про реальность.... Вполне себе задача - запустить редизайн фронта на отдельном поддомене. Да, не в каждом спринте такое затевать, но раз в пару лет продукт нет-нет, да замутит что-то такое

Называеться кроссдоменная авторизация. Недавно настраивали на одном проекте. Чуть не здурели.
Идея разделения - это хорошо. Но с CORS и с Cookies вы поимеете большую головную боль еще даже на этапе разработки. Например, вы так просто не сможете читать куки с другого домена, если хоть один домен на http. Оба должны быть на https. Это означает надобность создавать самоподписной сертификат для localhost. Такие серты хоть и типа работают, но как-то оно всё ненадёжно, хром, например, видит, что это за сертификат и всё-равно подсвечивает его красным, хоть всё и работает.
С корсами чуток проще - замапьте в hosts какой-нибудь хост типа myapp.local на локалхост и прописывайте корсы для этого хоста. А за фронтендом стучать в myapp.local:5173/
